# Correct way to get Windows CPU utilization for multiprocessor

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

What I want to achieve is I can get every CPUs utilization (I have 4 CPU core, so I expect I can get all of them like in `resmon.exe`) and the sum of them (Like in the `TaskManager.exe`)

[image: resmon.exe]

I have read on some soure on how I can get the processors utilization is by doing some math on the CPU time. I tried to use [`NtQuerySystemInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation) to get the necessary data.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <winternl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ntdll.lib")

typedef struct
_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION_R {
    LARGE_INTEGER IdleTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER KernelTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER DpcTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER InterruptTime;
    ULONG InterruptCount;
} SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION_R;

static long long toInteger(LARGE_INTEGER const & integer)
{
#ifdef INT64_MAX // Does the compiler natively support 64-bit integers?
        return integer.QuadPart;
#else
        return (static_cast<long long>(integer.HighPart) << 32) | integer.LowPart;
#endif
}

class CPU
{
public:
    uint64_t prev_idle = 0;
    uint64_t prev_ker = 0;
    uint64_t prev_user = 0;
    uint64_t cur_idle = 0;
    uint64_t cur_ker = 0;
    uint64_t cur_user = 0;

    double get()
    {
        SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION_R *a = new SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION_R[4];
        // 4 is the total of CPU (4 cores)
        NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation, a, sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION_R) * 4, NULL);

        prev_idle = cur_idle;
        prev_ker = cur_ker;
        prev_user = cur_user;

        cur_idle = 0;
        cur_ker = 0;
        cur_user = 0;

        // 4 is the total of CPU (4 cores)
        // Sum up the SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION_R array so I can get the utilization from all of the CPU
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION_R b = a[i];
            cur_idle += toInteger(b.IdleTime);
            cur_ker += toInteger(b.KernelTime);
            cur_user += toInteger(b.UserTime);
        }

        std::cout << "Cur idle " << cur_idle << '\n';
        std::cout << "Cur ker " << cur_ker << '\n';
        std::cout << "Cur user " << cur_user << '\n';

        uint64_t delta_idle = cur_idle - prev_idle;
        uint64_t delta_kernel = cur_ker - prev_ker;
        uint64_t delta_user = cur_user - prev_user;
        
        std::cout << "Delta idle " << delta_idle << '\n';
        std::cout << "Delta ker " << delta_kernel << '\n';
        std::cout << "Delta user " << delta_user << '\n';

        uint64_t total_sys = delta_kernel + delta_user;
        uint64_t kernel_total = delta_kernel - delta_idle;

        delete[] a;
        // return (total_sys - delta_idle) * 100.0 / total_sys;
        return (kernel_total + delta_user) * 100.0 / total_sys;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CPU a;
    std::cout << "starting" << '\n';
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << a.get() << '\n';
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And to get the individual CPU utilization, I don't have to sum all of the CPUs, just choose one of the `SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION_R` array element.

My question is

1. Am I doing it right? Because when I check my program with the CPU utilization in the TaskManager.exe, it somewhat different.

[image]

2. Is there any better approach other than using `NtQuerySystemInformation` (Because Microsoft has mention "NtQuerySystemInformation may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic.")?

Comment: *"NtQuerySystemInformation may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic."* conscious lie i be say

Comment: [SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation#system_processor_performance_information): *Use [`GetSystemTimes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getsystemtimes) instead to retrieve this information.*

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I have see that, but "On a multiprocessor system, the values returned are the sum of the designated times across all processors.", I need to get each individual CPU as I have mentioned

Comment: Have you tried [Using Raw Performance Data Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/monitoring-performance-data#using-raw-performance-data-classes) with the WMI class `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor`?  BTW: I have test with `NtQuerySystemInformation` and `GetSystemTimes`, they returned the same value for me.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I think WMI does not gives me the access for the individual CPUs. Yes, `NtQuerySystemInformation` and `GetSystemTimes` can produce the same result, but `NtQuerySystemInformation` gives your more details and you have to sum up by yourself.

Comment: Querying `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor` will give you one "row"/"entry" for reach logical CPU in the system. For example, on my machine I have 12 logical CPUs and querying this class will give me 12 results (`Name` 0 to 12 respectively). As a side node, TaskManager can also show individual logical CPUs. Right click on chart, select "Change Graph type" from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve same thing and based on my research, standard windows task manager is a bad source of overall CPU load (image below). It seems that individual CPU Core loads are ok in task manager, but overall CPU load seems to be wrong.

I loaded all of my CPU cores, except one, using AIDA64 stress test, but task manager [shows 100% CPU load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAUjC.png), when it clearly isn't. But my similar program was showing same CPU loads as AIDA, expecially when I added DpcTime and InterruptTime to kernel time.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately, this question specifically asks about using a WinAPI call to query CPU utilization, so your answer does not address OPs problem.