# Calculating CPU usage per core by WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cpu-usage

I am trying to calculate CPU usage per core using C++ and WinAPI, but I am not able to do that properly. Thus, I have managed to calculate it by following:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation 0x8
#define SystemBasicInformation    0x0
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER IdleTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER KernelTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER UserTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER Reserved1[2];
        ULONG Reserved2;
    } SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION;
    typedef struct _SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION {
        ULONG Reserved;
        ULONG TimerResolution;
        ULONG PageSize;
        ULONG NumberOfPhysicalPages;
        ULONG LowestPhysicalPageNumber;
        ULONG HighestPhysicalPageNumber;
        ULONG AllocationGranularity;
        ULONG_PTR MinimumUserModeAddress;
        ULONG_PTR MaximumUserModeAddress;
        KAFFINITY ActiveProcessorsAffinityMask;
        CCHAR NumberOfProcessors;
    } SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION;
    //  SYSTEM_INFO  sysinf;

    if (argc<2)
    {
        printf("Please specify waiting time in seconds\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int nWaitSec = _wtoi(argv[1]);
    if (nWaitSec <= 0)
    {
        printf("Waiting interval in seconds should be positive integer\n");
        return -1;
    }
    typedef DWORD(WINAPI * PNTQUERYSYSYTEMINFORMATION)(DWORD info_class, void *out, DWORD size, DWORD *out_size);
    PNTQUERYSYSYTEMINFORMATION pNtQuerySystemInformation = NULL;

    pNtQuerySystemInformation = (PNTQUERYSYSYTEMINFORMATION)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"NTDLL.DLL"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION sbi;
    SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION * spi;

    DWORD returnlength;
    DWORD status = pNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemBasicInformation, &sbi,
        sizeof(SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION), &returnlength);

    spi = new SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION[sbi.NumberOfProcessors];

    memset(spi, 0, sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION)*sbi.NumberOfProcessors);

    status = pNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation, spi,
        (sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION)*sbi.NumberOfProcessors), &returnlength);
    int numberOfCores = returnlength / sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION);

    printf("Number of cores: %d\n", numberOfCores);
    static ULARGE_INTEGER  ul_sys_idle_old[32];
    static ULARGE_INTEGER  ul_sys_kernel_old[32];
    static ULARGE_INTEGER  ul_sys_user_old[32];

    float          usage = 0;
    float          usageAccum = 0;

    printf("\n\nWait for %d seconds\n", nWaitSec);
    Sleep(nWaitSec*1000);
    status = pNtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation, spi,
        (sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION)*numberOfCores), &returnlength);
    usageAccum = 0;
    for (int ii = 0; ii<numberOfCores; ii++)
    {
        ULARGE_INTEGER        ul_sys_idle;
        ULARGE_INTEGER        ul_sys_kernel;
        ULARGE_INTEGER        ul_sys_user;

        ul_sys_idle.QuadPart = spi[ii].IdleTime.QuadPart;
        ul_sys_kernel.QuadPart = spi[ii].KernelTime.QuadPart;
        ul_sys_user.QuadPart = spi[ii].UserTime.QuadPart;

        ULONGLONG kernelTime = (ul_sys_kernel.QuadPart - ul_sys_kernel_old[ii].QuadPart);
        ULONGLONG usertime = (ul_sys_user.QuadPart - ul_sys_user_old[ii].QuadPart);
        ULONGLONG idletime = (ul_sys_idle.QuadPart - ul_sys_idle_old[ii].QuadPart);

        ULONGLONG proctime = kernelTime + usertime - idletime;

        ULONGLONG totaltime = kernelTime + usertime;

        usage = (float)(proctime * 100) / totaltime;
        usageAccum += usage;
        printf("Core        : %u: Usage      : %f%%\n", ii + 1, usage);
    }
    usageAccum /= numberOfCores;
    printf("----------------\nAverage for the last %d seconds: %f", nWaitSec, usageAccum);
    delete[] spi;
    return 0;
}
```

Despite that fact, it seems to be calculated in a wrong way because its output data almost does not change. How could I find CPU usage per core appropriately?

Comment: Great question! The answer is likely undocumented.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: Try to refer tp [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation).It will return an array of SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structures, one for each process running in the system. These structures contain information about the resource usage of each process, including the number of handles used by the process, the peak page-file usage, and the number of memory pages that the process has allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three arrays are not updated in real time in your source code.So their value is always 0 in the loop.

```
static ULARGE_INTEGER  ul_sys_idle_old[32];
static ULARGE_INTEGER  ul_sys_kernel_old[32];
static ULARGE_INTEGER  ul_sys_user_old[32];
```

What you get is the CPU usage time that has been running for a long time, and the base is very large, resulting in basically unchanged.

You can refer to [Correct way to get Windows CPU utilization for multiprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898131/correct-way-to-get-windows-cpu-utilization-for-multiprocessor) and update your array to get the correct result.